# "Couldn't find executable named mono_odometer below ..."

Tags: navigation, odometry, ros-kinetic, viso2-ros, viso2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can successfully rosrun other executables such as `rosrun image_view image_view image:=/cv_camera/image_rect_color` and other packages including the listener and talker tutorial. I'm having trouble getting visual odometry from the viso2_ros package (http://wiki.ros.org/viso2_ros) following this tutorial (https://www.instructables.com/id/ROS-Visual-Odometry/) when trying to call `rosrun viso2_ros mono_odometer image:=/cv_camera/image_rect`. I get

```
Couldn't find executable named mono_odometer below /home/usr/catkin_ws/src/viso2/viso2_ros
```

but I've noticed mono_odometer is under /home/usr/catkin_ws/src/viso2/viso2_ros/src, Perhaps I need to change something in CMakeLists.txt? It looks the same as cloned from (https://github.com/srv/viso2). I already trade `chmod +x`-ing mono_odometer.cpp. It is probably some gap in my knolwedge.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328469/%22couldn%27t-find-executable-named-mono_odometer-below-...%22/) by [kevthomson](https://answers.ros.org/users/44015/kevthomson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2019-07-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turns out I wasn't even compiling mono_odometer. I had been using `catkin_make -DCATKIN_WHITELIST_PACKAGES="pkg1;pkg2"` to build only certain packages. I tried building only `viso2` using that command, but I checked ~/catkin_ws/devel/lib/viso2_ros/ and nothing had been built there. I rebuilt using the conventional `catkin_make` and now the node runs as expected. Maybe something else is going on there.

I thank @gvdhoorn for trying to help.

---

Originally posted by [kevthomson](https://answers.ros.org/users/44015/kevthomson/) with karma: 16 on 2019-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I already trade `chmod +x`-ing mono_odometer.cpp. It is probably some gap in my knolwedge.

have you built your workspace (ie: `catkin_make`d it) before trying to execute the node?

You cannot "run" a `.cpp` file. You have to compile it first, then link it into an executable binary.

The binary is what you run.

All of that is done automatically for you if you build your workspace.

---

The Instructables page you link to also mentions that in the *Building everything* section.

It forgets to tell you to also `source ~/odometry/devel/setup.bash` though. Without that `rosrun` and/or `roslaunch` will not be able to find any of your new nodes.

---

Edit:

> Also yes, I know one cannot run a .cpp, but can the binary, thank you for wording it correctly!

Then why did you `chmod +x` a `.cpp` file?

> I assume `odometry` is the name of the workspace, which is `catkin_ws` for me?

Yes, it is, but I used the name they give it on the page you linked to.

> So yes, I did `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`, which is also in my .bashrc, which should mean I don't need to do it anyway?

No, that's not entirely true.

You have to `source` a workspace whenever you add or remove packages to from it. Having a `source` line in your `.bashrc` doesn't help in those cases, unless you open a new terminal whenever you add or remove packages to from the workspace.

So if you don't, you still have to `source` your workspace after building it.

> Any other ideas why I'm not able to run the node? Any other common issues?

After having built your workspace, having `source`d the `devel/setup.bash`, what is the output of `rospack find viso2_ros`?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-07-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kevthomson](https://answers.ros.org/users/44015/kevthomson/) on 2019-07-14**:
I did `catkin_make`-ed my workspace.

Also yes, I know one cannot run a .cpp, but can the binary, thank you for wording it correctly!

I assume `odometry` is the name of the workspace, which is `catkin_ws` for me? So yes, I did `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`, which is also in my .bashrc, which should mean I don't need to do it anyway?

Any other ideas why I'm not able to run the node? Any other common issues?